# Trying to measure start current of a DC motor

Tags: dc, dc-motor

I have an 12V DV electric winch I am attempting to power with a power supply. I am only pulling about 150 lbs and I want to know what the...

1. Start up current
2. Running current

The winch starts and pulls the load with a 15A power supply but I was told that the starting current is likely higher than 15A and that I should use a power supply that can supply the start up current otherwise I run the risk of my power supply failing.

I have a DMM but it is only rated at 10A.

I was told to use a DC shunt resistor and test the voltage but I don't know which size to get. Do I get a 10A? 40A? 100A? I was told if it's too low I'll blow it but if it's too high I won't get an accurate reading.

So my questions...

1. If the winch runs on 15A is that good enough?
2. If no, then how do I measure the start up current?

Comment: `If the winch runs on 15A is that good enough?` How are you relating electrical current to how much this winch can pull?

Comment: Apply 2V to the motor and try to keep it stalled (if you fail, lower the applied voltage). Measure the current through the motor when it is stalled. Motor voltage / stall current = terminal resistance. If you know these: stall current is also starting current: so, at 12V, starting current is 12V/terminal resistance.

Comment: @KingDuken The power supply is rated for 15A. With a 15A power supply the winch can pull the load just fine.

Answer (score 1):

A shunt is a low value resistor that drops a small voltage proportional to current. They are rated by maximum continuous current and the voltage drop at that current. Typical 'full scale' voltage ratings are 50mV, 75mV, or 100mV.

Your multimeter's lowest voltage range is probably 200mV, so with a 100A 100mV shunt it would read Amps directly (100.0mV = 100.0A). In cases like yours the accuracy doesn't need to be very high, so you could use a 100A shunt and still get usable readings in the 0-15A range. Using a higher current shunt also has the advantage that it drops less voltage at lower currents, reducing voltage loss at the load and making the readings closer to what they would be without the shunt.

Most multimeters have a fairly slow response time with ~3 readings per seconds and averaging which might make it even more sluggish, so you won't see the true peak current. An oscilloscope would show you the true peak and the shape of the startup current. However the power supply can probably handle short current spikes anyway, so this may not be needed.

DC motors generally draw about 3~5 times more current at startup than at their rated output, so if your winch draws a bit less than 15A normally it could draw up to ~75A at startup *if the power supply lets it*. If your peak measurement is a only little over 15A it may be indicating the power supply current limit rather than what the motor would draw on a higher current supply (eg. a car battery). However provided the power supply is designed to run for short periods in current limiting (and is able to start the motor without problems) it should be OK. If the normal running current under load is under 5A and startup current reading is <15A then you should have nothing to worry about.

Comment: I don't know if this matters, but I first tried a 10A power supply and the motor wouldn't go, but it wanted to. And this winch will only run for about 10 seconds a few times a day.

Comment: Well that tells you one thing - the motor draws more than 10A at startup. But is it more than 15A? Perhaps. The 15A power supply _seems_ to be handling it, but long-term reliability is unknown. You could either hope for the best, or measure current and have some peace of mind. Here's a 50A meter complete with shunt on eBay for US$5 https://www.ebay.com/itm/Digital-Voltmeter-Ammeter-DC-0-100V-10A-50A-100A-Dual-LED-Amp-Volt-Meter-Shunt/283415378520?hash=item41fcdf7a58:m:mRbve6vOMvcZNt3ru6nqDOA

Answer (score 0):

You should not power a DC motor with a power supply. You should use an electronic speed control (ESC). The ESC will limit the current to about 150% of the rated current. That limit may be adjustable. Without and ESC, the current may be as much as 10X rated current at switch-on.